# Javascript 'arguments' Keyword

Tags: javascript

My understanding is that I can call `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)` to return the tail of an array.

Why won't this code return `[2,3,4,5]`?

```
function foo() {  
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
}

alert(foo([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you're only passing **one** argument — the array.

Try `alert(foo(1,2,3,4,5));`

Arguments are numbered from 0 in JavaScript, so when you start your slice at 1 and pass 1 argument, you get nothing.

Note that it can hamper optimization to allow the `arguments` object to "leak" out of a function. Because of the aliasing between `arguments` and the formal parameters, an optimizer can't really do any static analysis of the function if the `arguments` object gets sent somewhere else, because it has no idea what might happen to the parameter variables.

Comment: Would it be better, then, to copy the arguments?
`function foo() {
 var args = arguments;
 return Array.prototype.slice.call(args,1);
}`

Comment: The MDN article on the `arguments` keyword describes this optimization problem you mentioned:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 13):

`arguments` is an array-like object that lists the arguments and a few other properties (such as a reference to the current function in `arguments.callee`).

In this case, your `arguments` object looks like this:

```
arguments {
    0: [1,2,3,4,5],
    length: 1,
    other properties here
}
```

I think this explains the behaviour you're seeing quite well. Try removing the array brackets in the function call, or use `arguments[0]` to access the arry.

Answer (score 3):

Because `arguments` is `{0: [1,2,3,4,5], length: 1}`, which is an array-like object with one element. The tail of an array with one element is the empty array.

Either change the definition of the function:

```
function foo(arr) {  
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arr,1);
}
```

or call the function with:

```
foo(1,2,3,4,5);
```