# Mix in each Underscore method as a proxy to Collection#models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using the backbone library to perform the following:

```
var Persons = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'unknown',
        age: 18
    },

    over_18: function () {
        return this.filter(function (model) {
            return model.get('age') > 18
        });
    },

    under_18: function () {

        var persons_over_18 = this.over_18;

        return this.without(this, persons_over_18); // it does not work!! why?
    }
});

persons = new Persons([{age: 17}, {age: 27}, {age:31} ]);

persons.under_18().length; // 3 instead of 1
```

As you can see the method `under_18` is not working properly because it returns all the models 
instead of giving me just the models which age attribute is under 18.

So in order to debug my code, I decided to see the the [Backbone.js Annotated Source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-113),in particular the following code:

```
var methods = ['forEach', 'each', 'map', 'collect', 'reduce', 'foldl', ... ]; // and more

_.each(methods, function(method) {
    Collection.prototype[method] = function() {
      var args = slice.call(arguments);
      args.unshift(this.models);
      return _[method].apply(_, args);
    };
});
```

But the above piece of code is not clear to me and I still cannot make the first one work as I wish.

So my question is how can I fix the first code in relation to the second one?

Here is my code into jsfiddle.net  http://jsfiddle.net/tVmTM/176/

Comment: First issue -- you've got a typo in your code on the `return` statement line.  Second, try to please only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 3):

Lengthy answer to better understand the Backbone.js code:

In JavaScript, a "member" for an object can be referenced in two ways:

1. the usual `.` notation: `foo.say('hello');`
2. the `[...]` notation, with the string as an argument... a bit like an associative array:
   `foo["say"]('hello')`

In Backbone.js, each string in the `methods` array, defined just above this method, is iterated and added to the `Collection` prototype, so it is added to all classes that inherit (or extend) `Collection`.

In the function, the `arguments` keyword simply references all the arguments passed into the function, even if the signature is empty:

```
Collection.prototype[method] = function() { // <- empty signature here!
```

The slice without any arguments will transform the passed arguments into an array. Notice the use of `slice.call(...)` here (and refer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803947/javascript-arguments-keyword)).

```
var args = slice.call(arguments);
```

`unshift` then adds the Collection models array to the beginning of the array.

```
args.unshift(this.models);
```

Then we are actually calling the Underscore method (using the `[...]` notation) on the new array of arguments. Using apply, we pass the `_` as the first argument which will become the `this` scope (more information is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply))

```
return _[method].apply(_, args);
```

This allows you to do stuff like:

```
MyCollection.each(function (model) { ... });
```

instead of

```
_.each(MyCollection.models, function (model) { ... });
```

The resulting effect is **identical**! The former will just call the latter. :)

To answer your question, the problem in your case is that the `_.without` method does not accept two arrays, but an array followed by a list of arguments; the method you are looking for is called `difference` (look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469577/underscore-js-without-and-difference-methods-trouble)), but it is not mapped into the Collection, so you either map it yourself (replicating the code found in the Backbone source) or just use it directly:

```
return _.difference(this.models, this.over_18());
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tVmTM/177/

In my opinion, better just keep using `filter` as you did for the `over_18` method... Even better, put the `over_18` and `under_18` as methods in the Model (where they belong) and from the collection just use those.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It has been very clear. Anyway the second part does not work..check this link http://jsfiddle.net/tVmTM/176/

Comment: `_.without` does not want two arrays, but an array and a list of arguments... You should use `_.difference`. SO reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469577/underscore-js-without-and-difference-methods-trouble problem is that it is not mapped in Backbone so you have to actually use it from `_`. jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tVmTM/177/ . In my opinion, better put the methods on the model and use `filter` in the collection

Answer (score 0):

1) Each string in the  `methods` array corresponds to an underscore method, like `_.forEach`, `_.map`, `_.reduce` etc. For every string in `methods` a function is added to the `Collection` prototype that calls that underscore method, but passes the models in the collection as the first argument, followed by any options you pass in.

For example, say you have a collection called `Dogs` which contains a bunch of `Dog` models. Calling `Dogs.forEach(options)` will call a function which calls `_.forEach(Dogs.models, options)`. It's a convenience thing.

2) On line 2 you use `that` when I think you mean `this`. On line 3 you have an extra `.` after `without`.